# Is there a way to convert a string to an imported variable name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I have a function where a string is passed in with the same name as an imported variable. For example

```
import Stuff from 'stuff';

const x = "Stuff"
```

Is there a way to get the value of Stuff if all I have to work with is the string variation of the name? In this case "Stuff" is a string variation of the variable name Stuff, so I want to use Stuff, but all I have to work with is x.

I've tried something like

```
window[x]
```

but that doesn't seem to work for imported variables. Any ideas?

Comment: No, you can't do that - like with any other local variable. Make a `Map` of your desired keys and the imported values, then do a lookup.

Comment: What other things beside `Stuff` could the string `x` select? For a small selection, just do `if`/`else`

Comment: I guess I was just making it more complicated than it needed to be, I'll just use a map